# Is there a retirement home for "closed" meta questions?

Tags: discussion

I'm thinking primarily of tag cleanup requests, but this might apply to certain other questions, also.  The active questions list can fill up with things like tag cleanup requests.  At some point, action of one kind or another is taken on most, and these are put to bed.  Particularly after a tag has been removed, no further purpose is served by having the question in the active list.  Keeping it there pushes actual active questions further and further back where they lose visibility.  The same may apply if a decision has been made not to remove a tag.  Is there some form of inactive list where these can go, available if someone looks for them but not displayed in the active questions?

Comment: Well, technically once closed, they should sink further down off the active page. Failing that, you could always use the 'newest' question tag

Comment: They do sink, they just push everything else further down also.  Once questions get out of sight, they are pretty much ignored so there is not fresh activity to move them back up.  Unless somebody does a search or drills down through old posts, they are unlikely to find them.  A surge of tag cleanup posts over a few days buries posts that are still current.  Maybe we need a meta-meta site for infrastructure maintenance.